# array of string in c only storing last value given to it

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have an issue with my code. I am reading a shell script file and I am creating an array that should store every line from it. For some reason only the last line from shell file is stored in the array, from array[0] to array[3] I have the same value and I don't understand why. Code is bellow, if anyone can help. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char **line = NULL;
    size_t *len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("no arguments \n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *arr[255];
    int i = 0;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
    {
        arr[i] = line;
        printf("line is :%s", line);
        i++;
    }   
    printf("\n%s %d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("%s %d\n", arr[3]);

    free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output is:

```
line is :#!/bin/sh
line is :echo "line test test"
line is :ls -l
line is :echo "last line test"
echo "last line test" 0
echo "last line test" 0
```

Comment: `arr[i] = line;` is only storing a pointer to `line`, and `line` will be overwritten by the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: You are passing the wrong types to `getline`.  You should get warnings about that.

Comment: To add to AKX's comment, `arr[i] = line;` -> `arr[i] = strdup(line);`